# How to declare a numerical variable in java that is to hold a digit value with a fixed length of 3 digits always.

Tags: java, variables, integer, int, precision

How to declare a numerical variable in Java that is to hold a digit value with a fixed length of 3 digits always. That is if i input 0, it should be formated to 000, if i input 31 then it should be formated to 032 and if i input 100 then it should remain 100. I need this for receiving and storing three digit integer value that is sent via rest response as error codes. I tried the normal int and Integer but the preceeding zeros are always removed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The numbers 000, 031 and 032 do not exist. 0, 31 and 32 do exist. What you need is a formatted String not a number.

Comment: Please post you code for more reponse, if you just want display on 3 digit do `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("000");
     df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
     System.out.println(df.format(nb));`

Comment: @StephaneM: Note well that `031` does exist. It's an octal literal with a decimal value of 25.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a property of a numerical variable, but a way of formatting it (of converting it to a string).

It can be done with: `String.format("%03d", x)` (x being a numerical variable).

Comment: So after formatting the value then it should be stored as a string otherwise it may not work.

Comment: @geobudex I wouldn't do that: I would format it where needed

Answer (score 1):

This is a formatting problem rather than a type problem
you should look at the [String.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) method or the [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class

Answer (score 1):

> I tried the normal int and Integer but the preceeding zeros are always
>   removed.

This behavior is expected. **The int type cannot represent numbers with preceeding zeroes**; just as you want. To achieve *the 3-digit effect*, you have to format to a String everytime you want to display the integer.. You can do it this way:

```
String.format("%03d", number);  //number is the int.
```

If number is 4, using the code snippet above will output: `004`.

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!